# NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python

```
    file.write(newrecord)
```

NameError: name 'file' is not defined

This is an error that I get.

```
classa = int(input("What class are you in?"))
if classa == "1":
    file=open("class 4.csv", "a+")
file.write(newrecord)
```

File is clearly defined and I don't know why I receive this error.

Comment: what happens if classa is not "1" ?

Comment: @Alp I have made code for that but if I do enter 1 for classa I get the error.

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: @user2357112 for which line of code.

Comment: @BobStanley: All of them. There are only four. (And if examining the four posted lines is not enough to diagnose your error, you should take some time to learn about [how to post code usefully](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is off. Python handles blocks based on indentation. Additionally, as @davidism pointed out in the comment above, you're attempting to compare an int to a string.

Try this:

```
classa = int(input("What class are you in?"))
if classa == 1:
    myfile=open("class 4.csv", "a+")
    myfile.write(newrecord)
```

Assuming `newrecord` is defined somewhere above this in your code.

Edited the code again to satisfy Clayton's comment. `file` is a constructor function in Python from v2.2 - v2.7.

Comment: I was just suggesting you fold it into your answer so it's complete; I don't like upvoting answers that only address a single aspect of the problem (when the whole problem can be addressed of course; some problems posted here are just a cluster of awful).

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom Depends on what version of Python you're using. However, I'll change it for clarity's sake. Thanks for the suggestion.